# How to access a value in type from a list

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

This is the structure of my project

```
type A{
t1;
t2;
}

and B = var of A
and C = B list
type D = C list
```

Now I have a function with only D as a parameter. I need to assign t2 a unique value every time I call this function.

I guess I can't assign a value directly to t2, instead I need to return a new type with a new value of t2. I think that's how functional language work

My problem here is I don't know how to access this that value by using this function

I am still learning the syntax, if anyone can give me a example, that would be great

Comment: It's too far away from valid OCaml syntax.  Almost impossible to guess what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear at all.

If you want a to be a record where you can change one the fields, then you can use the keyword `mutable`.
If you have `type a = { t1 : int ; mutable t2 : int }`, then if `x` is a value of type `a`, you can use the syntax `x.t2 <- 9` for instance.

If I understand correctly, what you want to do would be:

```
type a = { t1 : int ; mutable t2 : int }
type b = Var of a
type c = b list
type d = c list

let func d =
  List.iter (fun c -> List.iter (function (Var a) -> a.t2 <- a.t2 + 1) c) d
```

Which can be rewritten (by eta-conversions)

```
let func = List.iter (List.iter (function (Var a) -> a.t2 <- a.t2 + 1))
```

This function will iterate over each `c` in your `d = c list` and for each of them will iterate all `b` that are just `Var a` for which it modifies `t2`.